# mysql wheel is not supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

i am trying to install mysqlclient but it getting error pls help 
thankyou.

```
  C:/desktop>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

> error

```
 mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

my python version is

```
C:\Users>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
(Intel)] on win32
```

Comment: Your Python is 32 -bit and you are trying to install a 64 -bit wheel. That won't work.

Comment: If you can't switch to 64-bit Python, There are 32-bit unofficial wheels for Windows [on this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient).

Comment: still not working , please help

Comment: code: 
(exampleTest) F:\Dbtest\exampleSLA>python                                                                          
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

(exampleTest) F:\Dbtest\exampleSLA>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp27-cp27m-win3
2.whl
mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
.

Comment: it is not working for ubuntu, Any one has idea about how to install mysqlclient wheel ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
mysqlclient is not working with 32 bit python at least for me.
so, I download Python 3+ of 64 bit. now it's working fine